# Having switched to sbcl, slime asks for *inferior-lisp* confirmation during close

Tags: slime

I was using `clisp` with Emacs-25.2 on Windows XP and Emacs-25.3 on Windows 7. Because `sbcl` has better `trace` support I switched to `sbcl-1.4.14` on both  Windows XP and 7. Both machines have `slime-20180804.1655` installed. When I close `slime`(using the command `sayoonara`) I get

```
Buffer "*inferior-lisp*" has a running process; kill it? (yes or no)
```

and I have to manually enter `yes`

I looked into the `slime` folder if there's a file like `stop-swank.lisp` or similar, there was none. How do I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you have slime-fancy loaded and are entering commands in the mini-buffer. Does the same thing occur if you enter "quit" rather than "sayoonara"?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes slime-fancy is loaded and I was entering the commands in the mini-buffer. When I enter 'quit' that confirmation didn't come up.  It must have something to do with the 'sayoonara' I guess.

Comment: It could also be peculiar to MS Windows. I have never seen on linux a request to close the buffer when using quit or sayoonara. Ideally it would be good to get comments from other MS Window users.

Comment: How about trying?:  `(remove-hook 'kill-buffer-query-functions 'process-kill-buffer-query-function)`  If that works, then you may wish to instead modify the function `process-kill-buffer-query-function` to have an exception for certain buffer-names or other criteria ...  Type:  `M-x find-function`

Comment: @m43cap yes this particular problem looks Windows specific because on my Mac with `sbcl` never came across such a thing.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for the comment. I will tinker with that hook script as soon as I get my hands on my Windows box. Typing `quit` instead of `sayoonara` fixed the problem though.